# How to run a post-hoc correction test on multiple chi-square test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, post-hoc, fishers-exact-test, bonferroni

I have run chi-square tests on occurrence of species across two time periods. As I have 1300 species I analysed them in bulk using a multiple loop function in R:

chitest1<- t(sapply(seq(nrow(SPECIES)), function(i)
chisq.test(SPECIES[i, c('boxT1','boxT2','urbT1','urbT2')])[
c('statistic', 'p.value')]))

The resulting chitest1 produces a dataframe with 1300 rows of chi square results:

Test statistic        P. value

1. X-squared = 394.54    3.367e-85
2. X squared = 19.90     0.00017   and so on...

Now I would like to run a post-hoc correction test on this and have been advised to do a fishers-exact test or a bonferroni. My questions are:

1. Can I easily peform a post-hoc test on the looped output dataframe (chisqtest1)
2. Which test would be the most appropriate and I would be so grateful of someone could point me in the right direction as to the package and syntax I would need.

This is a new area for me so constructive advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear about the analysis you've done so far: You performed 1,300 chi-squared tests, one for each species separately, on a 2x2 matrix for occurrences yes/no during two time periods before/after?

Comment: You can exploit the discreteness to improve upon Bonferroni greatly while maintaining FWER control; see https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Resampling+Based+Multiple+Testing:+Examples+and+Methods+for+p+Value+Adjustment-p-9780471557616